# Duplicate commit records with VSTS and GIT merge

Tags: git, merge, duplicates, commit, records

I googled for this duplicate commit records but could not find the solution. Here is my situation. We started using VSTS with GIT and created Dev branch for development. Following steps we are following to merge changes to remote Dev branch which is creating duplicate commit records for the same message/change:

1. Checkout remote dev branch locally.
2. Create local branch for each bug or feature from local dev branch.
3. Once the bug is fixed we stage and commit changes to local bug branch.
4. Publish local bug branch to remote and create pull request for review.
5. Once the reviewer reviews he approves and merges change to remote dev branch.

after step #5 we see two commits records with the same message and same pull request number but different commit ids in the branch history. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks

Santosh

Comment: Have you been using `git cherry-pick`?

Comment: no, we are pretty new to GIT and didn't know much about it. Should i be using cherry pick? At what step i should use cherry pick?

Comment: Does this happen with all commits involved in the pull request?

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether this be human error or something else.